# Display the fields properly in output panel while using actionRegion

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, actionsupport, outputpanel

I am using actionRegion for to show/hide the fields based upon picklist in Opportunity. When i am selecting the Stage picklist value is Closed Lost, then 4 text fields will be displays. It works fine. but the fields will not shown properly. what is the solution for to show these fields properly as like as remaining fields. Here i am attached the image to understand clearly.

[image]

Here i provided my code.

```
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
             <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
             <apex:commandButton value="save & New" action="{!quicksave}"/>
             <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity information" columns="2">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel > Opportunity Owner</apex:outputLabel>
                    {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Name}"/>

                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Stage"/>
                <apex:actionRegion >
                          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
                              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="ajaxrequest" />
                          </apex:inputField>
                </apex:actionRegion>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.AccountId}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Probability}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Type}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Amount}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.ForecastCategoryName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Sales_Office__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CampaignId}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.UI_Code__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Jobsite_Location__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.LeadSource}"/>

                <apex:outputPanel id="ajaxrequest">  
                  <apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Lost'}" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Reason_for_Loss__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Lost_To_whom__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Competitor_s_Price__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Competitor_s_MT__c}"/>
                  </apex:pageblockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.NextStep}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Description Information" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Description}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Are you rerendering the the outputPanel..?please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pageblocksectionitem to preserve formatting, more information can be found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm).

Example:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Owner"/>
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:inputField value="{!Case.OwnerId}">
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="comment"/>
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Edit:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                 <apex:commandButton value="save & New" action="{!quicksave}"/>
                 <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity information" columns="2">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel > Opportunity Owner</apex:outputLabel>
                        {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Name}"/>

                    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Stage"/>
                    <apex:actionRegion >
                              <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
                                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="ajaxrequest" />
                              </apex:inputField>
                    </apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.AccountId}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Probability}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Type}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Amount}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.ForecastCategoryName}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CampaignId}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.LeadSource}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputPanel id="ajaxrequest">
                <apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Lost'}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Reason_for_Loss__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Lost_To_whom__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Competitor_s_Price__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Competitor_s_MT__c}"/>
                </apex:pageblockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.NextStep}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Description Information" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Description}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

Comment: I am used this code for Stage field. Can you suggest the code for last four fields. my code is <apex:outputPanel id="ajaxrequest">  
<apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Lost'}" >
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Reason_for_Loss__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Lost_To_whom__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Competitor_s_Price__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Competitor_s_MT__c}"/>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>

Comment: Can you update your question with the formatted code, but can you include the entire page? Just that code is rendering properly for me so I'm thinking it's something further up on the page.

Comment: Actually, I think you just need to put columns="1" in your <apex:pageblockSection columns="1" rendered="{!Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Lost'}">

Comment: i added the complete code of VF Page in question. If i put columns="1" then it shows one by one in same column. but i want left to right. Reason for loss is beside the Lead Source and Lost to home under the Lead Source etc..

Comment: I updated my answer with your code, but you should be able to just pull that ouputpanel out of the pageblocksection and hide the header. Basically your outputpanel is being treated as 1 item inside the outer pageblocksection. Note: I removed some of your custom fields so don't use the full code.

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it. can you tell me one more.. In Custom VF Page for Opportunity, when selecting Stage field Probability and forecasting are not filling by default. In standard Opportunity page if we select Stage field by default Probability and Forecasting fields are filled. Is there any solution for this...?

Comment: Not sure, you may need to open a new question, I'm guessing you will have to mimic that behavior. This blog walks you through doing that http://www.opfocus.com/blog/dynamically-updating-probability-when-selecting-stage-with-visualforce-2/

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Reference [apex:actionSupport](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm), an example can be constructed:

For the example, make sure to give the VF Page a valid Opportunity Id like

```
apex/testPage?id=006i000000NMz1k
```

Controller:

```
    public class OpportunityExtension {

    public String reasonForLoss {get;set;}
    public String lostToWhom {get;set;}
    public String competitorsPrice {get;set;}
    public String competitorsMT {get;set;}

    public Opportunity opp {get;set;}

    public OpportunityExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sCon) {
        Id oppId = sCon.getId();
        if(oppId != null){
            this.opp = [SELECT Id, Name, StageName
                        FROM Opportunity
                        WHERE Id = :sCon.getId()
                        LIMIT 1];
        }
    }


    public void updateStageLossDetail(){
        if(opp.StageName != 'Closed Lost'){
            this.reasonForLoss = '';
            this.lostToWhom = '';
            this.competitorsPrice = '';
            this.competitorsMT = '';
            return;
        }
        this.reasonForLoss = 'Whoops';
        this.lostToWhom = 'The other guy';
        this.competitorsPrice = 'Way to low';
        this.competitorsMT = ':<';
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityExtension">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opp.StageName}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                                        action="{!updateStageLossDetail}" 
                                        rerender="StageLossDetail"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel id="StageLossDetail">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                        <apex:inputText value="{!reasonForLoss}"  label="Reason For Loss"/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!lostToWhom}" label="Loss to Whom"/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!competitorsPrice}" label="Competitor's Price"/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!competitorsMT}" label="Competitor's MT"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you tell me one more.. In Custom VF Page for Opportunity, when selecting Stage field Probability and forecasting are not filling by default. In standard Opportunity page if we select Stage field by default Probability and Forecasting fields are filled. Is there any solution for this...?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you have one  tag nested inside another  tag.  Try changing your Visualforce code to the following and see if this is the desired result

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
         <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="save & New" action="{!quicksave}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity information" columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel > Opportunity Owner</apex:outputLabel>
                {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Name}"/>

            <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Stage"/>
            <apex:actionRegion >
                      <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
                          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="ajaxrequest" />
                      </apex:inputField>
            </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.AccountId}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Probability}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Type}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Amount}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.ForecastCategoryName}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Sales_Office__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CampaignId}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.UI_Code__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Jobsite_Location__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.LeadSource}"/>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>


            <apex:outputPanel id="ajaxrequest">  
              <apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Lost'}" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Reason_for_Loss__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Lost_To_whom__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Competitor_s_Price__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Competitor_s_MT__c}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information" columns="2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.NextStep}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Description Information" columns="2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Description}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is because of page blockssection in pageblock section change code

```
<apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:pageblocksection>
        <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
        <apex:pageblocksectionitem/>
    </apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

in lasst use ur code